# println needs a message in android

Tags: java, android

in my google cloud message application. it shows error as null pointer exception : println needs a message e in android. i tried to change the code from :

```
Log.e("UnRegister Receiver Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
```

to:

```
String err = (e.getMessage()==null)?"UnRegister Receiver Error":e.getMessage();
Log.e("UnRegister Receiver Error", err);
```

but it's still the same error.please assist me.

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (mRegisterTask != null) {
            mRegisterTask.cancel(true);

        }
        try {
            unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);
            GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            //String err = (e.getMessage()==null)?"UnRegister Receiver Error":e.getMessage();
            //Log.e("UnRegister Receiver Error", err);
            Log.e("UnRegister Receiver Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
        }

        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Logcat :

```
02-28 22:58:35.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2812): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GCMIntentService-414538748674-1]
02-28 22:58:35.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2812): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
02-28 22:58:35.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2812):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
02-28 22:58:35.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2812):     at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:138)
02-28 22:58:35.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2812):     at com.example.fitness2.GCMIntentService.onRegistered(GCMIntentService.java:29)
02-28 22:58:35.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2812):     at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.handleRegistration(GCMBaseIntentService.java:296)
02-28 22:58:35.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2812):     at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:197)
02-28 22:58:35.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2812):     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
02-28 22:58:35.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2812):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-28 22:58:35.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2812):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-28 22:58:35.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2812):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
02-28 22:58:35.422: W/EGL_emulation(2812): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-28 22:58:35.774: V/GCMRegistrar(2812): Unregistering receiver
02-28 22:58:35.774: E/UnRegister Receiver Error(2812): Receiver not registered: com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver@5342460c
02-28 22:58:35.774: E/UnRegister Receiver Error(2812): > Receiver not registered: com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver@5342460c
```

Comment: hmmm, well, i don't see onDestroy in logcat log ... you didn't provide the code connected with stacktrace from log

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to print it manually. You can do it using `printStackTrace` as following

```
e.printStackTrace ();
```

All you have to do is to replace all `catch` code with this line.

Your `logcat` days that you are trying to unregister a broadcast receiver that is not already registered. (Read the final two lines) I think you have forgot to call register receiver at the beginning.

Comment: Replace my line with the e, log line. If you have got the same error copy it for me

Comment: Checkout my modified answer